# mysql view table performance

Tags: mysql

I just want to confirm

so i have 2 tables with exact same columns but different content
let's say table A and B
and i'm creating view table AB which is simply

```
select * from a
union
select * from b
```

when the data of each table gets big like millions will

```
select * from ab where `value`>1000
```

be as fast as

```
select * from a where `value`>1000
union
select * from b where `value`>1000
```

now the data is just several thousands so i don't have any issue at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options are really different.

Imagine we have

a : 4 million rows, 1 million with value > 1000

b : 2 million rows, 1 million with value > 1000

First solution :

```
select * from ab where value > 1000
```

You construct a temporary table of 6 million rows and then apply the filter value > 1000

Second solution :

```
select * from a where value > 1000
union
select * from b where value > 1000
```

You filter a with 1 million records, b with 1 million records and then union the results of 2 millions

In the first solution you works with a big temporary table of 6 million.
In the second you works with 2 little temporary tables of 1 million to construct a table of 2 million.
This is not the same.

A significant improvement could be to use `union all` if you know you have different results in a and b.
See benchmark here : https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/

Comment: I tried creating 2 tables with exact same structure and different values, created script to insert random data for millions of rows. the "view" solution is terrible. Very long time to load while the second solution is way faster. proven